# It is still possible to use magento 1 version 1.9.4.5 in ubuntu?

Tags: magento-1.9

So our client website still runs on magento 1 and he wants to at least fix it especially in front end. The problem is the client still wants to use the same version which I believe -v 1.9.4.x though we recommend the latest version but the client still insist. Is still possible to use that version at this time especially adobe doesn't support it anymore and remove download for it. Is there an alternative way to use the same version?

Comment: It is possible, but better use https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts